# Ответ 404 (Not Found) при помощи .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

В настоящий момент при переходе по этим ссылкам сервер отвечает `200 OK`

```
https://site.ru/catalog_tovarov.php?product=1000
https://site.ru/catalog_tovarov.php?product=1000bla
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, какие изменения необходимо внести в .htaccess, чтобы сервер:

1) Отправлял `200 OK` только при наличии цифр после слова `?product=`

2) Отправлял `404 (Not Found)` при наличии других символов (например букв)

Пример:

```
200    https://site.ru/catalog_tovarov.php?product=1000
404    https://site.ru/catalog_tovarov.php?product=1000bla
```

[image]

Содержимое текущего файла .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.сайт.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Не вижу смысла использовать .htaccess тут
ЧПУ нет. Можно на уровне php возвращать 404

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать так, если у вас php >= 5.2.0, без использования .htaccess

```
$product = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'product' , FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if ($product) {
        echo "Выводим материал";
        } else {
          header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
          echo "Материал который вы ищите удален или перемещен";
        };
```

Comment: Добрый день, VGlad. Спасибо за ответ. А можно это реализовать средствами .htaccess?

Comment: @caboke, можно, но для этого вам придется использовать ЧПУ.

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ catalog_tovarov.php?product=$1 [L]`

Comment: Добавил только что `RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+)$ catalog_tovarov.php?product=$1 [L]` в конец файла `.htaccess` - к сожалению, ничего не изменилось. Содержимое файла `.htaccess` приложил к сообщению.